# Equivalent definitions of essential supremum?

Tags: measure-theory, definition, supremum-and-infimum

I was studying about Lebesgue spaces and ran into the definition of essential supremum.

Actually I have seen two very similar definitions: Let $(X,\mathfrak{M},\mu)$ be a measure space and $f:X\to [-\infty,+\infty]$ be a measurable function. Then $$\text{ess sup}|f(x)|:=\inf\{c\in \mathbb{R}: \mu(\{x\in X:|f(x)|>c\})=0\}. \qquad(*)$$ Also you can find exactly the same definition where infimum is taken over $c>0$, i.e. $$\text{ess sup}|f(x)|:=\inf\{c>0: \mu(\{x\in X:|f(x)|>c\})=0\}. \qquad (**)$$

And I think that probably $(*)=(**)$.

It follows easily that $(**)\geq (*)$. But how to show the converse inequality?

Can anyone provide the rigorous proof, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\phi(c) = \mu \{ x | |f(x)| > c \}$. Note that $\phi$ is non increasing, so
$\phi(0) \ge \phi(c)$ for all $c \ge 0$.

Let $N_* = \inf_{c \in \mathbb{R}} \phi(c), N_{**} = \inf_{c> 0} \phi(c)$.
It is clear that $N_* \le N_{**}$.

If $\mu X = 0$ then $N_* = -\infty$ and $N_{**} = 0$, so they are not equivalent in general.

Suppose $\mu X >0$.

If $c < 0$ then $\phi(c) = \mu X > 0$, so
$\{c | \phi(c)=0 \} \subset [0, \infty)$
and so $N_* \ge 0$.

Suppose $\phi(0) = 0$, then $\phi(c) = 0$ for $c \ge 0$ and so
$0 = N_* = N_{**}$, otherwise $\phi(0) >0$ and
$\{c \in [0,\infty] | \phi(c) = 0 \} = \{c \in (0,\infty] | \phi(c) = 0 \} $ and so taking
$\inf$ we have
$N_* = N_{**}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! I will accept this answer as the best. Yeah in the case when $\mu X=0$ they are not the same but why in books authors does noe inlude this case? They just write measure space and do not mention that measure of whole space should be positive.

Comment: @ZFR: I don't know. I prefer to avoid such ambiguities.

Comment: So you mean we are considering measure space with $\mu(X)>0$?

Comment: I am a bit confused

Comment: I mean I would use the $N_{**}$ definition. Then it works nicely regardless of the measure of $X$.

Comment: Hmm. Let me ask you this: What forces you to think that $N_{**}$ works nicely regardless of the $\mu(X)$?

Comment: I would consider it strange to have the essential supremum of the function $f=0$ to be $-\infty$.

Comment: @copper.hat Referring to the below case in your answer: Can you please clarify how the infimum of a set of negative numbers be zero? 
Suppose $\mu X >0$.
If $c < 0$ then $\phi(c) = \mu X > 0$, so 
$\{c | \phi(c)=0 \} \subset [0, \infty)$
and so $N_* \ge 0$.

Comment: @texmex I am nor sure what you mean by the $\inf$ of a set of negative numbers. Note that $\phi(c) \ge 0$ for all $c$.

Comment: @copper.hat I am referring to the set of $c$ since the inf we are taking is over the set of $c$ right? $c<0$ in the case considered. Referring to the fifth new line in your answer. Please let me know if you need any clarifications.

Comment: @texmex I do not understand what you are asking. If $c \le 0$ then $\phi(c) \ge 0 $. So, for the purposes of the above, the $\inf$ with $c \in \mathbb{R}$ is the same as the $\inf $ with $c \ge 0$.

Comment: @copper.hat Please see below where I highlight the part from the above answer which I am not able to understand. "Suppose $\mu X >0$. If $c < 0$ then $\phi(c) = \mu X > 0$, so  $\{c | \phi(c)=0 \} \subset [0, \infty)$ and so $N_* \ge 0$." This is the case where $c<0$. To be clear, the case $c=0$ is taken as a separate case later in the answer. So in the case where $c<0$ how can $N_*$ - which is the infimum of all $c<0$ - be  a subset of  $[0, \infty)$.

Comment: @texmex It is the $\inf$ of $\phi(c)$, not $c$.

Answer (score 1):

If $c<0$, then
$$
\{x\in X:|f(x)|>c\}=X
$$

Since $\mu(X)>0$, the set set that appears in the RHS of ($*$) is contained in $[0,\infty)$.

Now we consider two cases:

- If $f=0$ a.e. then the sets in $(*)$ and $(**)$ are $[0,\infty)$ and $(0,\infty)$ respectively, so their infimums are both $0$.
- If $\neg(f=0$ a.e.), then $0$ does not belong to the set in $(*)$, and so the sets in ($*$) and $(**)$ are the same.

Comment: I have not read your answer in detail but are you considering the case $\mu(X)>0$? If yes then I know that they are the same. But what if $\mu(X)=0$?

Comment: @ZFR Then your measure space is not very interesting.

Comment: I don't think so. Because I reviewed many books in measure theory including Stein, Royden and others and most of them when they considering $L_{\infty}$ space they do not exclude the case when $\mu(X)=0$.

Comment: @ZFR Those books are operating under the tacit assumption that $\mu$ is not identically $0$. The property in question is false if the space has measure $0$. But then again, so is every theorem which has the words "almost everywhere" in its statement.

Comment: Thanks! Two more questions: 1) "The property in question is false if the space has measure 0." Which property are you talking about? 2) "But then again, so is every theorem which has the words "almost everywhere" in its statement." Could you explain this, please?

Comment: @ZFR The two definitions of essential supremum are not equivalent if the space has measure 0. The first one is $-\infty$ while the second one is zero. Also, I misspoke regarding theorems being false. It would be more appropriate to say they are vacuously true. For example, the dominated convergence theorem would be trivial, because every integral over the space is 0. This does not capture the “spirit” of measure theory, which is that sets of measure zero should be negligible. In particular, the entire space should never be negligible if the theory is to make any intuitive sense

Comment: @Reveillark Referring to the $c<0$ case: Assuming you are referring to the set $\inf\{c\in \mathbb{R}: \mu(\{x\in X:|f(x)|>c\})=0\}. \qquad(*)$ and not the set ${x\in X:|f(x)|>c\}$. Can you please clarify how the infimum of negative numbers can be zero or positive?